# Building a WordPress Page from a database table record

Tags: wordpress

I plan on collecting some data about a specific product with an input form and placing the data into a row of a custom WordPress table.  The next part of the plan is to have a custom template file read a row of the table and build a web page from it. Now the third part of the plan is where I need help: I need to create a permalink that, when put into a browser, will end up calling my custom template with the record  to build.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing each row through URL you need to enter the data in **WP_Posts** table ..

Insert all the records in Wp_Posts rather than custom table .. all other values can be inserted in **wp_post_meta**.. then you will not have to manage the URLs as well as table ..It will be done by WordPress automatically.

Please find the links to add records in the Wp_posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Insert records in wp_post_meta
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

Create your template in your theme folder and add the following on top:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Your template */ ?>
```

Then add a page, and select this template with the template selector on the right. The permalink of the page will now use your template.